Evaluating $ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{x_n} $, where $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}$, without proving $x_n=\cot{\frac\pi{2^{n+1}}}$?

Let the sequence $(x_n)$ be such that $x_1 = 1$ and, for $n\geq 1$, $$x_{n+1} = x_n + \sqrt{x_n^2 + 1} 
$$
Find
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n}{x_n} $$

Is there any way to do this without proving by induction that
$$ x_n = \cot{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}} $$
And if there is not, how could I think of that as a solution?

Why would you avoid such an easy proof, and what do you mean by "how could I think of that as a solution?" and how are we expected to prove that "there is not" (if we believe this is the case)?

Well, to me it's not an easy thing to see, like I wouldn't have thought of going into trigonometry within the solution - that's what I meant.
